# Time Series Forecast - Logistic Regression Not Respecting Cap and Floor

Tags: r, time-series, regression, logistic-regression, facebook-prophet

I am trying to fit a curve for approximately 2 years worth of datetime data posted here, and forecasting a year's worth of 5-minute intervals. I'm using [Facebook Prophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/) with this [input data](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/thomasnield/501b355a24a3a5f736b2c8510bfb0098/raw/b9dedf2f4170e3dc20cf7c1d2f39f2c2ef66b954/gistfile1.txt).

Whether I do a linear or logistic fitting, I do get some outrageous values that are larger or smaller than any of the inputted values (the linear model even produces negative values). I tried to leverage a logistic model to specify a floor and cap, but that didn't stop deviant numbers either.

For instance, of the 105120 forecasted records outputted, 25131 are lower than the specified floor. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or if there is an expected behavior I'm not interpreting correctly?

```
library(prophet)
library(dplyr)

url <- 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/thomasnield/501b355a24a3a5f736b2c8510bfb0098/raw/b9dedf2f4170e3dc20cf7c1d2f39f2c2ef66b954/gistfile1.txt'

df <- read.csv(url) %>% mutate(y=log(y))

#floor and cap
lower = quantile(df$y, .05)
upper = quantile(df$y, .95)

df <- df %>% mutate(floor = lower, cap = upper)

# modeling
m <- prophet(df, 
             changepoint.prior.scale=0.01, 
             growth = 'logistic')

future <- make_future_dataframe(m, periods = (24*12*365), 
                                freq = 60 * 5, 
                                include_history = FALSE)  %>% mutate(floor = lower, cap = upper)
# forecast every 5 minutes
forecast <- predict(m,future)
#prophet_plot_components(m, forecast)

write.csv(forecast %>% 
            select(ds, yhat_lower, yhat_upper, yhat) %>% 
            mutate(floor = exp(lower), 
                   cap = exp(upper),
                   ln_yhat_lower = yhat_lower,
                   ln_yhat_upper = yhat_upper, 
                   ln_yhat = yhat,
                   ln_floor = lower, 
                   ln_cap = upper,
                   yhat_lower = exp(yhat_lower), 
                   yhat_upper = exp(yhat_upper), 
                   yhat = exp(yhat)
                   ), 'problem_output.csv')
```